# What is a good method for sharing source code among 3-4 developers that does NOT require it to be Open Source?

Tags: asp.net, version-control

I'm a newbie developers and building an application with 3 other remote developers.  I've only worked alone until now, and now I need a way to share my source code with the other developers on the project.  All of the project sites out there (SourceForge, Codeplex, Google, etc) seem to be aimed at Open Source development I'm not interested in making our code available to the world, I'm just looking for a method of sharing the code among the four of us.  What is the best known method...or how is this usually accomplished?

Comment: Do you need to "Lock" the source codes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, you need a version control repository which is remotely accessible.  [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) is excellent and very widely used; [Git](http://git-scm.com/) is another good option.

You could set up your own repository - you'll need a server which all devs can access via ssh, or via Apache/WebDAV - or use a hosted service, like [Beanstalk](http://beanstalkapp.com/), [Project Locker](http://www.projectlocker.com/), [Unfuddle](http://unfuddle.com/), [SVNsite](http://www.svnsite.com/start), etc.

Comment: I work at ProjectLocker and can tell you that you can host Subversion and Trac with us for free if your team is <= 5 and your codebase <= 500 MB.

Answer (score 5):

Set up a [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) repository (can be accessed across http).

There is an excellent [online free book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) detailing pretty much everything you need to know about Version Control with Subversion

Answer (score 3):

http://beanstalkapp.com/

Answer (score 3):

Set up a Subvserion repository (http://subversion.tigris.org/).  You can control who may view your data through accounts, plus it gives you document versioning.  When paired with a Http server, you can even view the source directly in a browser.

Subversion has all sorts of plugins for Eclipse and even Visual Studio, I believe.  Tortise SVN is a stand-alone SVN client you may like, although I recommend an IDE-integrated plugin.

Subversion also goes well with a continuous integration server, such as Continuum.

Answer (score 3):

Hosted: http://wush.net is another Subversion hosting platform.

Or, if you can host your own server, check out the VERY easy to use and VERY free VisualSVN Server: http://www.visualsvn.com/server/

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what computing resources you have available, but the easy choice is to use a central server with say [SVN](http://subversion.tigris.org) to which you all have ssh access using a public key.  You can probably rent such a service for around $10 per month.

If you don't like central servers, you can try [Mercurial](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/wiki/) or `git` and ssh back and forth between your personal development machines.

If ssh is problematic, git actually enables you to send patches to each other by email (probably Mercurial does too).  Ben Lynn's [Git Magic](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~blynn/gitmagic/) tutorial explains.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an online source control (like SVN or Git), and share it only with your team members. You should look into [Unfuddle](http://unfuddle.com/), it's a free source control/project hosting, complete with bug tracking system. I use it for my personal projects and it's awesome.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution is [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/). Subversion is a free source control system that is ideal for your requirement.

You can use many other support tools like [Tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) to make the things more easier.

Here is one of the [cheat sheets](http://www.abbeyworkshop.com/howto/misc/svn01/) that describes commands of SVN.

Most of the Web hosting providers support easy one click installation of SVN on their servers. ex : [Dreamhost](http://www.dreamhost.com) So you can get a setup done very easily.

[CVS](http://www.nongnu.org/cvs/) is another Source control system that are used widely but I haven't seen any providers that support easy installation of CVS but there should be. You can have support tools for CVS such as [Tortoise CVS](http://www.tortoisecvs.org/) as well.

I don't think you are interested in visual source safe (Microsoft Proprietary and not over Web) so I am not going to add information about it here. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a source control repository. It's a pretty big topic, I'm really not sure where the best place to start reading about it would be. I'm sure [the Wikipedia article on Revision Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) will at least give you a bit of an overview.

This seems like a decent introductory series as well: [Source Control HOWTO](http://www.ericsink.com/scm/)

Answer (score 0):

Subversion works just fine over http/https.  It is an open source project, but you can use it for whatever purposes you want.

http://subversion.tigris.org/

Answer (score 0):

Most modern source control systems work well.  Subversion is a common one.  Which operating system will the developers be running?

If you just want to get up and running quickly with something, check out a hosted subversion system like www.beanstalk.com or www.unfuddle.com.

Subversion is open source, and I know you don't need it, but there are a lot of options here.  If on Windows, check out Tortoise SVN.  If on a Mac and you don't want a command line client, check out Versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually setup google code to only allow viewing/editing by registered members. And I don't think they force any licenses either.

Answer (score 0):

We currently use VSS but are in the process of migrating everything over to [Source Gear Vault](http://www.sourcegear.com/vault/) because VSS makes jumping out of our third story windows a common thought...

Here is a free solution with premium options available... https://freepository.com I have not tried this one.

Answer (score 0):

Try github. It will cost you $12/month though.

Answer (score 0):

Just use devunity.com. upload your code via zip or import it from svn and thats it. lets you collaborate around code instantly.